# Dragon Age Inquisition- In Your Heart Shall Burn

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

(In your heart shall burn) I have died while turning the trebuchet consistently. I would like to go to other places to level up but I cannot figure out how to leave Haven. Please help and be specific. Thank you! Also, is there a way to swap characters since there isn't a camp site?

Answer (score 2):

That quest is a major plot point. Once you start it you cannot leave or change companions. Your best bet is to load a save prior to starting it.